# How do I explain this xml version of .proj file?

Tags: vb.net

```xml
<Compile Include="H:\business\shared\Dropbox\vb.net\plugrush.designer.vb">
  <Link>plugrush.designer.vb</Link>
  <DependentUpon>plugrush.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="H:\business\shared\Dropbox\vb.net\plugrush.vb">
  <Link>plugrush.vb</Link>
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="H:\business\shared\Dropbox\vb.net\keysadder.vb" />
<Compile Include="H:\business\shared\Dropbox\vb.net\adbrite.vb" />
```

Is there a documentation somewhere? Why the entry for keysadder different from entry for plugrush.designer.vb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keysadder` appears to be a regular class whilst `plugrush` is a form. They're different because every form actually consists of three files that are linked together:

- `formName.vb`
- `formName.Designer.vb`
- `formName.resx`

**Documentation references:**

- [**MSBuild Project File Schema Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx)
- [**Walkthrough: Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx)